# What is a simple server architecture to stream a video file?

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, html5-video

I've a large video file (mp4 format. few gbs in size).

I want the user be able to seek randomly to any portion of the video without having to buffer (kinda like youtube)

I would prefer a HTML5 video player on the browser (esp on iOS devices)

What would a typical server architecture look like? I am very new to media servers, so I wondering if FMS (flash media server) or Wowza media server solve this problem or is a self hosted solution simpler? Do I even need a full blown media server? Again, I am noob when it comes to media servers and stuff.

Also any recommendations for a video player?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In nowadays, video streaming doesn't need a special video streaming server any more.

For your application, you can just use Apache or Nginx, and fetch the HTTP link of the video content to the iOS device, the iOS device will do video streaming via HTTP transport.

Comment: Doesn't that only work for HLS? And I go with HLS what video player should I use for cross browser access?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your infrastructure, I would recommend Microsoft smooth streaming: http://www.iis.net/download/smoothstreaming

It allows adaptive bitrate, and will work on various players including Flash, Silverlight, HTML5, and iOS players.

It is also free and only needs IIS to run. I believe you may also now be able to use it on Azure CDNs too.

Comment: Will this work with most open source video players out there? Lot of them support HLS or RTMP out of the box.

Comment: Smooth streaming supports Apple's HLS if configured correctly.

Comment: If I go with HLS (which makes obviates needs for traditional media server), then what video player makes sense on the client side? My understanding is that out of the box only safari supports HLS.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into Adobe's [HTTP Dynamic Streaming](http://www.adobe.com/products/httpdynamicstreaming/). This is a good solutions if you're looking to avoid a media server altogether. It is a process of preparing your content using the f4fpackager tool (free) and then an Apache web server and the HTTP Origin Module (free).

There are also ways to extract the packaged content so you can serve up the content from any web server or something like Amazon S3.

If you're okay with dropping the dollars on a media server FMS will do what you are asking and I'm pretty sure Wowza will too (I'm not as familiar with Wowza though).

Comment: Interesting. Having a simple http server is definitely appealing. Apple's HLS protocol lets do that (after you index the media file) and is supported in ios and android devices. How does HTTP Dyanmic streaming compare? Will it work on ios devices?

Comment: HDS doesn't work on iOS but HLS is supported by Flash Media Server. I'm not sure about moving the indexed files for HLS out of FMS to a simple server.

Answer (score -1):

What you are mentioning with seeking can be achieved with [Progressive download](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_download) which is supported by most HTTP servers.

For more advanced use cases I'd suggest taking a look at [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/) and the [nginx-rtmp-module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) to do **real** [streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media#Protocols).